# R homals not working on dichotomous matrix

Tags: r, factor-analysis

I have a covariates matrix (n= 759, p = 175) with tons of missing data and I wanted to see if there are some similarities in the missingness pattern across the samples.
Since I am not used to work with binary data, I read about some methods and came across the very interesting `homals` R package.

From `is.na(data_covariates)` I removed the non informative features (no sample was a complete case, so I left all samples in) and was left with the 759 x 164 matrix `data_covariates_missing`, which I passed as argument to homals().

(**Edit**: I also removed two duplicate rows)

The command `homals(data=data_covariates_missing)` resulted in an error

```
Error in qr.default((1/sqrt(w)) * x) : 
NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

and lots of warnings, all with the same message:

```
In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

I played around with  `ndim, rank` and `level` from the `homals()` argument but had no luck. Inspecting the `homals` function code or vignette was not helpful, neither was searching StackOverflow.

By construction my matrix has no missing or infinite values so I really can not interpret the error and the warnings.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide sample data so people can play with it?

Comment: do you have negative values for which sqrt() is not defined? could 1/0 be an issue?

Comment: @KotaMori, @DirkNachbar thanks for your comments, they pointed me to the right issue: my data were coded as logical and not as numeric. Adding the line `for(j in 1:ncol(data_covariates_missing)) data_covariates_missing[,j] <- as.numeric(data_covariates_missing[,j])` before the `homals()`call did the trick.